# div multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как переписать код, чтобы он выбирал нужный элемент со списка и вставлял его в некий div.j-select__chosen, после, если нужно при нажатии на этот элемент, он обратно возвращался в список.

Сейчас написал код, который работает, но он не универсальный, сейчас можно добавить/удалить/добавить, а после нельзя опять удалить добавленный элемент, вот код:

```
$('.j-select__dropdown__item').one('click', function() {

        var $this = $(this);

        var chosen = $this.closest('.j-select').find('.j-select__chosen');

        $this.appendTo(chosen);

        $('.j-select__chosen *').on('click', function() {

            var $this = $(this);

            var dropdown = $this.closest('.j-select').find('.j-select__dropdown__scroll');

            $this.appendTo(dropdown);

            $('.j-select__dropdown__item').on('click', function() {

                var $this = $(this);

                var chosen = $this.closest('.j-select').find('.j-select__chosen');

                $this.appendTo(chosen);
            });

        });

    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="j-select">
  <div class="j-select__chosen"></div>
  <div class="j-select__selected">
    <div class="j-select__selected__value">Игры</div>
    <svg class="icon icon--arrow-down">
      <use xlink:href="#icon--arrow-down"></use>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="j-select__dropdown">
    <div class="j-select__dropdown__scroll">
      <div class="j-select__dropdown__item">Игры-0</div>
      <div class="j-select__dropdown__item">Игры-1</div>
      <div class="j-select__dropdown__item">Игры-2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Есть какие-то мысли по этому поводу?

Answer (score 0):

Сам решил. После переноса элемента не срабатывал клик на него, чтобы удалить с выборки, нужно было всего-то делегировать клик на нужный элемент.